Ubuntu 24.04 & Eclipse 4.32 : cannot edit file
On Ubuntu 24.04 & Eclipse 4.32 I cannot edit java file. I can copy past with mouse, but with keyboard, nothing appears. I can create new file with keyboard. Sometimes I can write into a file, but it's very rare. When I click on the editor, where there is no text, if there is a window open behind Eclipse, it opens and Eclipse is minimized. I also have that with Eclipse 4.31 and 4.30. It's like an invisible window who gets the keyboard focus. Reboot without any other than Eclipse gives same behavior. With Ubuntu 22.04 and Eclipse 4.32, it was well working.
Thanks

Can you try starting eclipse with the environment variable GDK_BACKEND=x11? While I haven't heard about the issue you are describing, there have been issues involving Wayland in the past.

Yes I did, same issue, I have rollback to 22.04.
